# Use DataFields in Rest URL in ExtJS to access Context.io API

Tags: rest, extjs, field

I have two Question Regarding Rest API in EXTJS.

1. How can I use fields to make rest URL dynamic?
2. How can I add authentication key to access Context.io in my Rest.Proxy?

This is my solution, but I am not sure if I have done it properly, or not. I am pretty new in ExtJS, so my question may be basic, but I appreciate your help.

```
Ext.define("EmailFolders", {
  extend: "Ext.data.Model",
  fields: ["id", "label"],

  proxy: {
    type: "rest",
    url: "lite/users/:" + id + "/email_accounts/:" + label + "/folders"
  },

  reader: {
    type: "json"
  },

  headers: {
    CONSUMER_KEY: "KEY FROM CONTEX.IO",
    CONSUMER_SECRET: "SECRET FROM CONTEXT.IO"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`store.getProxy()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-getProxy) to make rest URL dynamic and to pass the authentication keys in headers. Proxy have methods

1. [`proxy.setUrl()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#method-setUrl) to sets the value of url.
2. [`proxy.setHeaders()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#method-setHeaders) to sets the value of headers.

You can check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2mr9)

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        // Set up a model to use in our Store
        Ext.define('User', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: ''
                }
            }

        });

        Ext.define('MyStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'User',

            listeners: {
                beforeload: function (store) {
                    var proxy = store.getProxy();

                    //if you want, you can also set here url inside of beforeload
                    //proxy.setUrl(url);

                    /*
                     * You can use {proxy.setHeaders} to set the values from CONTEX.IO
                     * After ajax request see your request parameter in network analysis below 2 headers are passed in request header
                     */
                    proxy.setHeaders({
                        CONSUMER_KEY: "KEY FROM CONTEX.IO",
                        CONSUMER_SECRET: "SECRET FROM CONTEXT.IO"
                    });

                }
            }
        });

        let store = new MyStore();
        //Set the dynamic url here
        //This {url} will be dynamic whatever you want to pass
        store.getProxy().setUrl(url);

        store.load(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert('Open console to see reposne..!')
        });

        /*
         You can also pass url inside of load funtion
        */
        new MyStore().load({
            url: url + '/' + 1,
            callback: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still I have difficulty to use oAuth1. Is it possible for you to provide me an Example that uses oAuth1 to access the API?